# Constructing Counterfactuals and Estimating Prevalence

Tags: prediction, inference, multiple-imputation, treatment-effect

I'm a social scientist working on a research project where I try to estimate the prevalence of lying in responding to a certain sensitive question. The way I estimate it is to rely on a quasi-experimental setting where a major event happen in the middle of a public opinion survey and compare the people's responses to certain questions before (control) and after (treatment) the event. Each individual in the survey sample is only asked once, but with the assumption that the event is exogenous and the progression of the survey is uncorrelated with personal characteristics (which appeared to be the case after some checking), the attitudes of the treatment and the control groups are comparable.

My hypothesis basically suggests that there are two main types of individuals, those who lie about their attitude after the event, and those who don't. I have a measure that I believe should increase if one is lying, and decrease if not. Formally, it means that

$y^{i,T}_{z}>y^{i,C}_{z}$ if $i$=liar, and

$y^{i,T}_{z}<y^{i,C}_{z}$ if $i$=non-liar,

where $y$ is the measure for lying, ${T,C}$ indicate treatment status, and $z$ indicates actual treatment assignment. I wish to estimate the prevalence of the behavior of lying in my sample, that is, the ***proportion*** of people in the treatment group who might have lied about their preferences. The problem is that only one of the state is observed given the nature of the survey, so I need to estimate the counter-factual using some methods. More specifically, I wish to know:

$\frac{\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{I}(y^{i,T}_{z}>y^{i,C}_{z})|z=1)}{\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{I}(y^{i,T}_{z}<y^{i,C}_{z})|z=1)}$.

But given the nature of the survey, I only know $y^{i,T}_{z=1}$ but not $y^{i,C}_{z=1}$, for $i\in {T,C}$, so I need to estimate the counter-factual in order to calculate this proportion. My question is: what would be the best way to do this? So far I have tried two things: (1) do a simple linear prediction from the regression equation on all the individual in the treatment group but change their treatment status from 1 to 0. (2) treat this as a missing-date problem and use various multiple imputation method to create the counter-factual. I personally prefer the second method since it takes into account the uncertainty in constructing the counter-factual. But I haven't not seen any published work employing multiple imputation in such a way, so I'm not entirely sure whether this approach is appropriate. I would appreciate if someone could tell me whether these methods are valid and/or whether there is any existing method that I can use for this task. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Should the inequality sign be $<$ in your second inequality?